# how to read text files in keras using os.walk and converting to batched dataset

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I have text files that I need to analyse in keras and tensorflow i read the file paths using the os.walk and added them to list am then trying to read the text content and batch them using keras and tensorflow as follows

```
classes = []
labs={}
read_files = []
labels = []
path = "./data"
for root,folders,files in os.walk(path):
    itt = 0
    for folder in folders:
        labs[folder] = itt
        itt+=1
        classes.append(folder)
    for file in files:
        file = root+"/"+file
        file_class = file.split("/")[-2]
        labels.append(labs[file_class])
        read_files.append(root+"/"+file)


dataset = tf.data.TextLineDataset(read_files)
dataset = dataset.batch(batch_size)
print(next(dataset))
```

These is not the exact code since am working on several files but in general that is all I do till I get the error

when i run the code above the last line throws an error

```
File "/home/kim/Desktop/programs/python/text_processing/prog/main.py", line 10, in <module>
    0.2,32)
File "/home/kim/Desktop/programs/python/text_processing/prog/text_process.py", line 44, in load_data
    print(next(train_set))
TypeError: 'BatchDataset' object is not an iterator
```

I was am wondering why this code cannot work,am using `tf 2.0.0` in conda will appreciate any help in how to solve this
or even a suggestion on a better way to do this, am still wondering also how I can sp-lit my data to validation and training set

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
print(next(iter(dataset)))
```