# understanding what keras and TensorFlow to use in text classification

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I was trying to classify my text in tensorflow and keras and every time I tried using the keras to read my files from my directory then it would through and error that the features for reading the text was not available yet it is included in the documentation

I made my own file reader functionality which is here [how to read text files in keras using os.walk and converting to batched dataset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64666169/how-to-read-text-files-in-keras-using-os-walk-and-converting-to-batched-dataset) and now trying to vectorize my text using keras preprocessing then again the module is not available

as asked in the comment I was trying to use keras https://keras.io/api/preprocessing/text/ guide and the one https://keras.io/examples/nlp/text_classification_from_scratch/ here which uses the vectorizing, I started digging into uisng tf to make tokens from the text and I found how to vectorize the text here https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/text/word2vec

but now the problem was that I could not use the functions because I could not understand it very well my code was as follows

```
train_dataset = get_files_from_dir(train_path,batch_size=batch_size, seed=seed) # calls the fetch text which returns dataset of text and labels batched
text_ds = train_dataset.map(lambda x, y: x) # get featues only (text with no labels)

def vec_maker(text): 
    tokens = text.lower().split()
    vocab, index = {}, 1 # start indexing from 1
    vocab['<pad>'] = 0 # add a padding token
    for token in tokens:
        if token not in vocab:
            vocab[token] = index
            index += 1
        self.vocab =vocab
        return text
```

now my problem is how do I map the `text_ds` to the function to make the vectors because if I try passing the variable as function arguments it direct is says that

```
File"/home/kim/Desktop/programs/python/text_processing/prog/text_process.py", line 78, in vec_maker                      
    tokens = text.lower().split()                                                                                           
AttributeError: 'MapDataset' object has no attribute 'lower'
```

help and explanation will much be appreciated

Comment: Could you guide us to the Keras API you're referring to so we we can have a better understanding of what you want to achieve? What datatype are your dataset elements currently when you iterate through them?

Comment: @AmirMousavi I updated the question with the reference I was using and also what I have tried thanks